# Why associated types in rust need explicit lifetime annotation?

Tags: rust

I'm working with a trait which cannot be touched like this(minimized):

```rust
// The associated version
trait Testable {
    type T;
    fn test_it(&self, x: Self::T) -> bool;
}
```

Then I try to `impl` it with, say, `i32`:

```rust
impl Testable for i32 {
    type T = &str;
    fn test_it(&self, x: Self::T) -> bool {
        x.is_empty()
    }
}
```

However, I got compiler error:

```
type T = &str;
         ^ explicit lifetime name needed here
```

The associated type `Self::T` is just on the input parameter of method `test_it`. Why does the compiler claim that I have to provide lifetime annotation?

Note that if I change `T` to generic type like:

```rust
// The generic version
trait Testable<T> {
    fn test_it(&self, x: T) -> bool;
}

impl Testable<&str> for i32 {
    fn test_it(&self, x: &str) -> bool {
        x.is_empty()
    }
}
```

This time the code compiled without error.

The problem is

(1) why I have to provide lifetime annotation in the associated version since the type only appears at the input parameter side?

(2) Why the generic version compiled? Are there any deep differences between the two versions?

Comment: Have you run `rustc --explain E0637`? It's simply not allowed.

Comment: @cafce25 Can you explain further why this is not allowed? I read doc on E0637 but I still don't understand the design reason.

Comment: @Ireina well, the lifetime is part of the generics of a type. If it weren't that Rust sometimes uplifts this requirement, you'd always have to specify it. In this particular case, Rust doesn't make an exception to the rule, you have to specify the lifetime.

Comment: @BlackBeans Thank you. I understand rust often need lifetime annotation on references. Could you explain further why the generic version compiled without error(why lifetime annotation this time is not necessary?)?

Comment: @Ireina The mechanism that makes lifetimes optional sometimes is called "lifetime elision", and it's explained in the [rustnomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html).

Comment: My guess would be that in the first case, there are no lifetime annotations you could put in that would make it compile. You'll have to change the trait to make it work with `T = &str`, whereas in the second version, you could actually place lifetime annotations which the compiler can also instead figure out for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the associated type is chosen by the trait, whereas the generic parameter is chosen by the caller. So with this code:

```
impl Testable for i32 {
    type T = &str;
    fn test_it(&self, x: Self::T) -> bool {
        x.is_empty()
    }
}
```

The compiler needs to be able to know everything about `T` without looking at any other part of the code. But it can't: there is no way to know the lifetime of the reference just by looking at this code (btw the only lifetime that can work here is `'static`).

On the other hand with this code:

```
impl Testable<&str> for i32 {
    fn test_it(&self, x: &str) -> bool {
        x.is_empty()
    }
}
```

`&str` is an incomplete type since it's missing the lifetime, but that's ok because the type will be filled-in on the call site (like all template parameters).